# char pointer keeps changing unintentionally

Tags: c++, pointers, binary-search-tree

I'm working on a Binary Search Tree.
The program is supposed to store all the words inside the tree in order.

But every time the insert function is called, the 'root' node is effected.

Header

```
typedef char* CharPtr;

class BST
{

public:
    BST();
    ~BST();
    BST (const BST&);


void insert (CharPtr);
void printBST () const;

private:
    struct Node;
    typedef Node* NodePtr;

    struct Node{
        CharPtr word;
        int count;
        NodePtr left, right;
    };

    NodePtr root;

    // other private functions
    void PRVinsert (NodePtr&, CharPtr);
    //bool findNode (const NodePtr&, CharPtr)const;
    void inorderPrint (const NodePtr&)const;
};
```

I want `root->word` to remain the same throughout the program but it keeps changing. What am I doing wrong?

Implementation

```
// public function
void BST::insert (CharPtr currentWord){
    PRVinsert(root, currentWord);
}

// private function
void BST::PRVinsert (NodePtr& currentRoot, CharPtr w){

    if(currentRoot == NULL){
        NodePtr temp = new Node;
        temp -> word = w;
        temp -> left = NULL;
        temp -> right = NULL;
        temp -> count = 1;

        currentRoot = temp;
    }
    else{
        // compare two words
        int k = strcmp (currentRoot->word, w);

        if ( k > 0 )
            PRVinsert (currentRoot->left, w);
        else if ( k == 0 )
            currentRoot->count += 1;
        else
            PRVinsert (currentRoot->right, w);
    }

}
```

Comment: hint: structural problems with headers can be avoided if using automated indenting.

Comment: you **must not** use `new` without `delete` later on! You're making a new node that  that isn't temporary, but lives on forever everytime you do `new Node`!

Comment: `typedef`ing pointers is very often a bad idea. and you should be using `nullptr` instead of `NULL`. And is there any (good) reason why you aren't using `std::string` instead of `char*`?

Comment: Are you sure it's the *pointer* that keeps changing, not the contents of the memory it points to? I wonder because ***all*** your nodes only have a pointer to the "word", not a copy of it. So if you use a single buffer as argument to the `PRVinsert` function then *all* nodes will point to that single buffer. The solution is to not use pointers for strings, but `std::string`.

Comment: Also, it's your code, so I presume you wrote it intentionally like you did: in `currentRoot = temp`, you replace... the current root. And that is, at some point, your root node. So, the program does what you tell it to.

Comment: Please post a minimal usage example that exhibits the problem.

Comment: @UnholySheep yeah it's part the requirement for this assignment to use `char*`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I suspect that too. What can I do to make the 'root' pointer only effected once?

Comment: Also thanks for all the prompt replies guys. I'm very very new to all this I'm trying my best not to be a nuisance.

Comment: *Copy* the string: Allocate memory for it (remember the terminator) and copy into the new memory. Make your `word` pointer point to this new memory. Remember to free the memory when you free the node.

Answer (score 0):

@SomeProgrammerDude has nailed your issue.  You need to make a copy of that string for storage.  To my eye, what really sticks out is that your struct Node doesn't have a constructor, nor a destructor to handle its own storage requirements.  Scope, contructors and destructors are without contest the most important features of C++.

You should consider these changes to BST::Node:

For C++98:

```
struct Node
{
    CharPtr word;
    int count;
    NodePtr left;  // <-- defining one variable per line is a good habit
    NodePtr right; //     to have and is a very common coding guideline.

    Node(const CharPtr w) : count(1)
    { 
        word = new char[strlen(w) + 1]; 
        strcpy(word, w); 
    }

    Node(const Node& other) 
       : word(NULL)
       , count(other.count)
       , left(NULL)
       , right(NULL)
    {
        if (other.left)
            left = new Node(*other.left);
        if (other.right)
            left = new Node(*other.left);
        if (other.word)
        {
            word = new char[strlen(other.word) + 1];
            strcpy(word, other.word);
        }
    }

    ~Node() 
    {
        delete left;   // calling delete NULL is fine, testing would only add extra noise.
        delete right;
        delete[] word; 
    }

private:
    Node& operator=(const Node& other); // avoid problems
};
```

For C++11, if your teacher lives in the 21st century:

```
struct Node
{
    CharPtr word{};
    int count{ 1 };
    NodePtr left{ nullptr };
    NodePtr right{ nullptr };

    Node(const CharPtr w)
    { 
        word = new char[strlen(w) + 1]; 
        strcpy(word, w); 
    }

    Node(const Node& other) : count(other.count)
    {
        if (other.left)
            left = new Node(*other.left);
        if (other.right)
            left = new Node(*other.left);
        if (other.word)
        {
            word = new char[strlen(other.word) + 1];
            strcpy(word, other.word);
        }
    }
    Node() = delete;
    Node(Node&& other) = default;
    Node& operator = (const Node&) = default;
    Node& operator = (Node&&) = default;

    ~Node() 
    {
        if (left) delete left;
        if (right) delete right;
        delete[] word; 
    }
};
```

Now, you will have to remember that your destructor will delete all branches and leaves below it, if `left` or `right` are not null.  Update these pointers immediately so you don't accidentally delete branches you intended to keep when moving stuff around in your tree.

This will change your Insert() function:

```
void BST::PRVinsert (NodePtr& currentRoot, CharPtr w)
{
    if (currentRoot == NULL)
    {
        currentRoot = new Node(w);
        return; 
    }

    // compare two words
    int k = strcmp (currentRoot->word, w);

    if ( k > 0 )
        PRVinsert (currentRoot->left, w);
    else if ( k == 0 )
        currentRoot->count += 1;   // <-- this is the line that was being hit all the time
                                   // when node->word was not allocated correctly.
    else
        PRVinsert (currentRoot->right, w);
}
```

And greatly simplifies BST's copy constructor and destructor.

```
BST::BST(const BST& other) : root(NULL)
{
    if (other.root)
        root = new Node(*other.root);
}

BST::~BST()
{
    delete root;
}
```

Comment: added `word = new char[strlen(w) + 1];` before `strcpy(word, w);`
and now it's working as intended. Thank you!